# Where to download MariaDB 10.3 over IPv6?

Tags: centos7, ipv6, yum, mariadb

CentOS 7 server with only IPv6.

When I try to use,

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

It tries to connect via IPv4 and fails, is there a IPv6 compatible repo somewhere that has MariaDB 10.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://archive.mariadb.org/ is IPv4 however it lists the following as a mirror contain a Yum repository of a specific version that has an IPv6 address:

http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.3.9/yum//centos73-amd64/

Comment: Thank you, how would I add that repo to my centos 7 server?

Comment: @user1155594 Use a text editor to change the baseurl.